# A way to express how one feels after an exhausting wait before results are known!

Tags: expression-choice

What adjective or expression can describe the state of a person after a very wearing wait? Like the wait for the  results of an important examination,of  a decisive political election or  of   critical  medical analysis?

Comment: I think we might need a little more detail. In what sense? What type of person? For instance, "anxious" and "calm" might both apply. Two different people might be in these two disparate states after a wearying wait.

Comment: It could depend whether the result is to one's liking or not.

Comment: I am thinking about the wait before results are known.

Comment: @Emrakul - I am not thinking about a specific type of person,  a wearing wait can affect everybody  even if to different degrees!!

Comment: You say "**after** a very wearing wait." That seems to imply the wait is over, and the results are now known. But your question title seems to imply this weary person is still not sure of the end result. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't **weary** apply?

weary: adj., feeling or showing tiredness, especially as a result of excessive exertion or lack of sleep

Comment: "Weary" is a great suggestion, but it's possible to go further: "Wait-Weary Fans Flock To Oregon Ducks for Title Hopes" ... "Wait-weary royal watchers soldier on as new clues point to imminent birth"

Answer (score 1):

Someone may be [on tenterhooks](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-tenterhooks.html) or [distraught](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/distraught) while awaiting an important report.

The first few synonyms given for [bundle of nerves](http://thesaurus.com/browse/bundle+of+nerves) (as in distressed) may be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Nerve-wracking* would be an apt way to describe the waiting experience. To describe how a nerve-wracking wait leaves a person feeling, perhaps ***overwrought*** or ***wrung out*** would do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that we don't know what kind of psychological factors might be influencing the anticipatory state our subject finds themselves in. The situations you describe would engender apprehension and anxiety in some people, but election results might give rise to positive excitement in others. I would choose a word that you understand to describe the emotional state (x) that you want to attribute to the waiting and then say: "...feeling x after such a wearing wait.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that *weary* is a good word. Also *anxious* or *anxiously*: "He was *anxious* to get the results of his exam."

**Some other suggestions**

nervous

antsy

Comment: You could add **angst**, too. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/angst#angst_3) says: "a strong feeling of worry about .. what will happen in the future."